# How to get the HttpServletRequest / ServletInputStream in play framework

Tags: playframework

Before using play framework , I can use codes below to get the raw post data,

```
  ServletInputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
  if(inputStream!=null){
       String xml = StreamUtils.copyToString(inputStream,Charset.forName("utf-8"));
       System.out.println("xml: "+xml);
       EventMessage eventMessage = XMLConverUtil.convertToObject(EventMessage.class,xml);
       ......
       return;
  }
```

when using play framework ,the play.mvc.Http.Request seems has no method to get the inputstream, is there any method to get the 
ServletInputStream in play?

Answer (score 1):

In your Play controller, you can access the [request](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/play/mvc/Http.Request.html), from there you can get the body of the request which will contain the String you are looking for:

`public static Result index() {
  String xml = request().body().asText();
  ...
  return ok("ok);
}`

Note: you can also use the method `asXml()` of your body.

For more information: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaBodyParsers